# Почему не работает svg mask?

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg

Необходимо вырезать по форме path

```html
 <svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <mask id="p" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <path d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
            </mask>
            <image mask="url(#p)" href="img.png" width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"></image>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Что делать должна маска, вырезать по форме path или  обрезать, что еаходится за границами path?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вырезать по форме path

Comment: да и maskContentUnits принимает только целый числа - без float

Comment: @MaximLensky всё не так однозначно В свое время [Юлия Бухвалова](https://career.habr.com/buhvalova-y) ведущий специалист по SVG делала исследования на эту тему, оказалось, что можно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  и получается что спецификаwия ошибается вместе с разработчиками ?

Comment: @MaximLensky спецификация SVG  на w3C написана очень запутанно. модель obejctBoundingBox говорит, что размеры (width, height) должны быть в процентах или в долях от единицы где 1 = 100% userSpaceOnUse должен быть в единицах измерения,( не в процентах ) А на самом деле можно указывать в процентах, но не везде Короче очень запутанный вопрос

Comment: `@Alexandr_TT я ваще про саму модель, что если указать для маски вот такое поведение obejctBoundingBox то единицы счисления ведутся не от всей страницы а от места расположения исчисления то есть .5px по идее должны быть 50% - х.з как то так - а по факту кукишь это о path а circle/rect/ellips сплющивается и всё

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Во-первых нужно привести в соответствие размеры `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` При этих значениях он будет захватывать размер холста SVG
  `100х100px`
- `<path d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>` - 'это
  сектор, который укладывается в размеры меньшие одного пикселя.
  Поэтому, без преобразований вы его вряд ли увидите. Нужно либо его
  увеличить, либо уменьшить `viewBox`, чтобы они соответствовали друг
  другу.

Выбираю вариант `viewBox="0 0 1 1"`

Вот так выглядит форма маски:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path fill="red" d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
</svg>
```

**Теперь есть два варианта работы маски:**

1. Вырезать по форме маски: `fill="white"` остальное, что вне формы маски отбрасывается
   Такой режим соответствует работе `clipPath`:

Исходное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Вырезаем

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
        <mask  id="p"  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"> 
                <path fill="white"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
        </mask>
        <image mask="url(#p)"  href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNrx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
        </svg>
```

2. Вырезать отверстие по форме path и показать, что находится вне его

То же интересный вариант. Можно увидеть фон или вторую картинку, которая находится под верхней картинкой, к которой применен фон Подробнее [здесь](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1936)

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >  
        
        <mask  id="p"  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">  
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
                <path fill="blue"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
        </mask>
        <image mask="url(#p)"  href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNrx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
        </svg>
```

### Update

Если нужен адаптивный вариант, то указывается в процентах `width` `height` в шапке SVG

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
        <mask  id="p"  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"> 
                <path fill="white"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
        </mask>
        <image mask="url(#p)"  href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNrx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
        </svg>
```

Или оборачиваете SVG в родительский контейнер и задаете его размеры в относительных координатах

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
        <mask  id="p"  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"> 
                <path fill="white"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
        </mask>
        <image mask="url(#p)"  href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNrx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
        </svg>
 </div>
```

Comment: а можно как то указывать значения не в px  а в %?

Comment: @Artyom в каком именно месте?

Comment: в атрибуте d path

Comment: @Artyom   в атрибуте d path всегда только `px` Если нужен адаптивный вариант, то указывается в процентах width height в шапке SVG

Comment: ну в clipPath можно у атрибута d указывать в %

Comment: @Artyom Вы спутали с CSS  clip-path: polygon(92.32051% 40%, 93.79385% 43.1596%, 94.69616% 46.52704%,)  и там нет атрибута `d`

Comment: я именно в svg clipPath это делал, и что за плюсы? Я пометил ответ как решение

Answer (score 2):

### Работа маски с двумя изображениями

Нижнее изображение будет абстрактный узор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верхнее изображение, к которому будет применяться маска

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- При `<path fill="black"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>`

  Верхнее изображение с ромашками прорезается и становится видимым
  через это отверстие  нижнее абстрактное изображение

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >  
        
        <mask  id="p"  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">  
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
                <path fill="black"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
        </mask>   
        
               <!-- Абстрактный узор -->
        <image   href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNrx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
           <!-- Ромашки -->
        <image mask="url(#p)" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KF4L.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
        </svg>
```

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
    <path fill="white"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
```

Верхнее изображение (ромашки) при `fill="white"` остается нетронутым по форме маски, а остальное, что не вошло в маску вырезается и  становится видимым нижнее абстрактное изображение fill="black" у `<rect`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >  
        
        <mask  id="p"  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">  
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
                 <path fill="white"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path> 
        </mask>   
        
               <!-- Абстрактный узор  -->
        <image   href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNrx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
           <!-- Ромашки -->
        <image mask="url(#p)" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KF4L.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
        </svg>
```

- 

При `fill="red"` маска становится полупрозрачной

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >  
        
        <mask  id="p"  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">  
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
                 <path fill="red"  d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
        </mask>   
        
               <!-- Абстрактный узор  -->
        <image   href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNrx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
           <!-- Ромашки -->
        <image mask="url(#p)" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KF4L.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
        </svg>
```

- При добавлении в маску строки  с окраской в белый цвет, появляются новые
  возможности

```
  <path fill="red" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.035" 
    d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >  
        
        <mask  id="p"  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">  
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
                 <path fill="red" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.035" d="M.5,0 A.5,.5 0 1 0 1,.5 L.5,.5 L.5,-.1"></path>
        </mask>   
        
               <!-- Абстрактный узор  -->
        <image   href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNrx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
           <!-- Ромашки -->
        <image mask="url(#p)" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KF4L.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" ></image>
        </svg>
```

Comment: он на тостере мне вспомогательные вопросы задаёт - кучу целую - буду игнорить его

Comment: @MaximLensky Сегодня побеседовали с ним. Он просто не понимал, зачем нужны плюсы. Вроде понял, поставил первый плюс.

Comment: ну мне плюсы до лампы а вот что касается научить хотя бы основам - вот это тяжело